# rake db:migrate does not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-migrations

I am updgrading a redmine instance from a very early version. I am doing exact what the tutorial says. However command rake db:migrate rails_env=production doesn't modify the database correctly. There are a lot of fields not added to tables. I checked out the schema.rb file and it looks fine. The command ran without any error. I can tell from the output there are a lot of new indexes generated. I did a db:schema:load and didn't work either. How can I migrate the data? I think I have two options.
1. do a real db:migrate
2. create a fresh new version database and load data from old database, need instruction too

Any advise is appreciated.

Comment: I think you mistakenly migrated the development database, try this command `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate`

Comment: Thank you!!! I am typing in rails_env in lower case and it doesn't give me error!

Comment: Hey Lewis it could be more helpful if you make my comment upmark. This helps other to find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RAILS_ENV=production must be in upper case. Credit to Vivek Parihar.